# Remove commit message from azure devops pipeline run web page?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I know how to change the runName (also known as Build.BuildNumber) but as shown here [image: the picture] the commit message also shows up (this is the pipeline page in devops) even though it's not part of the name that I set. This behavior is also present when I don't change the name, it just looks like `yyyyMMdd.rev <commit message>`.

I don't want the message there because the BuildNumber that I set describes the pipeline run better, and the commit message could be confusing. Is it possible to remove the commit message from this list? Note that this is defined by the new yml pipelines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Sprint 209 / October 2022, you can set a new pipeline property in the yaml

```
appendCommitMessageToRunName: false
```

which will remove the latest commit message from the pipeline run.

Announcement:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2022/sprint-209-update?tabs=yaml

and the specific documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pipeline?view=azure-pipelines#pipeline-stages

Comment: Nice, changed the accepted answer to this.

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid that now there is not a setting or workaround which can remove the commit message from the build title. As it is the default behavior currently.

The user voice of disabling append commit message after the buildNumber has been submitted to Microsoft development. You can check [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1030999/enabledisable-appending-the-to-the-title-of-every.html) to vote it up or [submit a new feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) request of your own.